# Implementing url rewriting in Java Play Framework

Tags: angularjs, playframework, url-rewriting

I am working on Play Framework(2.3.7)+AngularJS+Simple Spring Project.

I need to implement Url rewriting for the application.

example input URL:

> localhost:9000/app/views/main/actoredit/actorid1234

Basically, *localhost:9000/app/views/main/* is common for all HTML pages.

example output URL::

> http://mysite/actoredit/actorid1234

Comment: Can you use Play's standard redirect https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaActions#Redirects-are-simple-results-too?

Comment: but Rewriting is simply is a translation of one URL to another, what i need is (to be bit more specific)                                                                example input URL:localhost:9000/app/views/main/actorEdit.html?id=123  to                                                                                       example output URL::http://mysite/actoredit

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your issue. What URL do you want to type the user in the browser? And from which URL should the HTML be actually loaded?

Comment: Take a simple eg like                                                                           example: input URL:   sitename.com/app/views/main/home.html#index/        output url visible to user:    sitename.com/index     .

Comment: Azar, you just repeat without explaining. What do you mean with input and output URL?

Comment: i am very sorry. Currently my url is like http://localhost:9000/app/views/main/home.html#index/   and i want a clean url for my application like gmail. ;)

Comment: I think what you want is deploying your application. Hm, this is not explained easily and I can't cover this here. But an easy possibility is to deploy it to the cloud. There are many companies offering this service. For 3 exist an tutorial in Play's docs https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/DeployingCloud.

Comment: Thanks very much  kris  :)